# Resolved: Mocking Angular Dialog afterClosed() for unit test

Tags: angular, testing

I have troubles with mocking popup data for unit testing. Getting an error like: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'showFilterModal' of undefined**
What am I doing wrong?

**FilterComponent**

```
public openFilterModal() {
  this.filterModal = this.modalService.showFilterModal(this.filtersOptions, this.userRole, 'bills');
  this.filterModal.afterClosed
    .subscribe(
      (result) => {
        this.selectedFiltersAmount = result.total;
        this.filtersOptions = result.filters;
      },
      (err) => {

      });
}
```

The idea was to create fake service with necessary observables and functions. Much thanks @Naren

**Correct test mocking:**

```
describe('Component', () => {
  let component: Component;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;

  const mockModelService = {
    showFilterModal: 
    jasmine.createSpy('showFilterModal').and.returnValue({ 
      afterClosed: of({
        total: 1,
        filters: null,
        reqObj: {
          status: 'active',
        }
      })})
    };

   beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     imports: [NecessaryModules],
     providers: [
      { provide: LocalModalService, useValue: mockModelService }
     ],
     declarations: [ Component]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create subscription after close modal', () => {
    component.openFilterModal();
    expect(mockModelService.showFilterModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.selectedFiltersAmount).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock the `modelService` and put in the `providers` while creating the component, and Spy on the `service methods` and define expected values.

You could try like this, But make sure, you updated the necessary changes accordingly your component. If there's any error let me know.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import YourModelService from '/path/serives'


const mockModelService = {
  showFilterModal: jasmine.createSpy('showFilterModal').and.returnValue({ afterClosed: of({
  total: 1,
  filters: null,
  reqObj: {
    status: 'active',
  }
} })
}

describe('testing', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [YourComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: YourModelService,
          useValue: mockModelService // <-- here mocked the service
        }
      ],
      schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    });
  })
  
  it('should create subscription after close modal', () => {
    component.openFilterModal();
  
    expect(mockModelService.showFilterModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(afterClosedSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.selectedFiltersAmount).toBe(1);
  });
})
```

Comment: Got an error: TypeError: this.filterModal.afterClosed.subscribe is not a function

Comment: Can you check once again, updated little bit

Comment: Same issue. I put correct providers but it's not helped. Also "YourModelService" I made public into main component, but it's not helped.

Comment: You need to show us what you're doing, We can't assume what;s in your file. Provide all the spec code, then will see

Comment: I have changed your code little bit, like that and it works, and I have removed afterClosedSpy, just checking changed values:
         const mockModelService = {
            showFilterModal: jasmine.createSpy('showFilterModal').and.returnValue({ 
            afterClosed: of({
               total: 1,
               filters: null,
               reqObj: {
               status: 'active',
            }
         })})
  };

Much thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question. Much thanks man!